# Can zepter help with std feature propagation?

Tags: features

Zepter has been great for pointing out runtime benchmark features that need propagating. I use it like so:

`zepter lint propagate-feature --feature runtime-benchmarks --left-side-feature-missing=ignore --workspace --feature-enables-dep="runtime-benchmarks:frame-benchmarking"`

Have people used it for checking that the `std` feature mappings are all done correctly too?

(Also asking the question to raise awareness that the cool tool exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question!

Yes it can check arbitrary feature propagation. In the Polkadot-SDK we configure it for three features: `std`, `runtime-benchmarks` and `try-runtime`.
You can see the full config file that contains the exact commands [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/ea4085ab7448bb557a1558a25af164cf364e88d6/.config/zepter.yaml).  ORML is using a very similar config file [here](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library/blob/b45942ea1973288c448ee58b07e1d33b28bb0343/.config/zepter.yaml).

One gotcha to look out for, is in the release process. `cargo release` strips dev-dependencies, and therefore all feature propagations to dev-dependencies need to be remove before releasing. This was just recently discovered. `zepter transpose features strip-dev-only` should do the trick, but please [open an issue](https://github.com/ggwpez/zepter/issues) if it does not.

Comment: Thank you for making the tool - it removes a lot of tedium!